# Cs_show doesn't trigger

Tags: latex3

I am a beginner in Latex3.
The test MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \my_mod:nn #1#2 {
  % store #1//#2 in \l_tmpa_int
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#1}{#2} }
  % compute (#1)-\l_tmpa_int*(#2)
  % make sure to surround operands with parentheses
  % so that when #1 is an expression (e.g. 3-2)
  % the order of arithmetic will not change
  \int_eval:n { (#1) - \l_tmpa_int * (#2) }
}
% define LaTeX interface
\newcommand{\mymod}[2]{
  \my_mod:nn {#1} {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\mymod{5}{3}\mymod{6}{3}\mymod{7}{1+2}%201
\end{document}
```

And at this stage is working fine. It prints "201" as expected.

Next I tried to see what's inside the `\my_mod` function, so I can get a better understanding about *Latex3*.
I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \my_mod:nn #1#2 {
    % store #1//#2 in \l_tmpa_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#1}{#2} }
    % compute (#1)-\l_tmpa_int*(#2)
    % make sure to surround operands with parentheses
    % so that when #1 is an expression (e.g. 3-2)
    % the order of arithmetic will not change
    \int_eval:n { (#1) - \l_tmpa_int * (#2) }
}

\newcommand{\showw}[2]{
    \cs_show:c \my_mod
}
% define LaTeX interface
\newcommand{\mymod}[2]{
    \my_mod:nn {#1} {#2}
    
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\mymod{5}{3}

\mymod{6}{3}

\mymod{7}{1+2}%201

\showw{3}{7}
\end{document}
```

And at this stage the TexStudio failed to compile yielding *Undefined control sequence. \showw{3}{7}* error.
I have to mention that the same error yielded when I changed `\cs_show:c` function with `\cs_show:N`.

How can I use `\cs_show` function in a proper way?

Comment: Why `\cs_show:c`? It should be `\cs_show:N`. But you just get the definition and absorb two more arguments, doing nothing with them. And there's no definition of `\my_mod`

Comment: If you'll run the first **MWE**, you'll see that it is compiled without errors. And for me, if some TeX code is compiled without errors or warnings, is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\cs_show:N` just logs the definition of the following control sequence and does not show its “working”.

Note also that `\my_mod:nn` and `\my_mod` aren't related in any way as far as TeX is concerned. You define the former, but not the latter and showing it will produce “undefined”.

You can see the workings, actually, using `unravel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unravel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \my_mod:nn #1#2 {
    % store #1//#2 in \l_tmpa_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#1}{#2} }
    % compute (#1)-\l_tmpa_int*(#2)
    % make sure to surround operands with parentheses
    % so that when #1 is an expression (e.g. 3-2)
    % the order of arithmetic will not change
    \int_eval:n { (#1) - \l_tmpa_int * (#2) }
}

\newcommand{\mymod}[2]{
    \my_mod:nn {#1} {#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hbox{\unravel{\mymod{5}{3}}}

%\mymod{6}{3}

%\mymod{7}{1+2}%201

\end{document}
```

The `\hbox` is to avoid spurious effects due to `\everypar` when TeX is trying to typeset the result. You will see 63 steps, of which I show only a few.

```
======== Welcome to the unravel package ========
    "<|" denotes the output to TeX's stomach.
    "||" denotes tokens waiting to be used.
    "|>" denotes tokens that we will act on.
    Press <enter> to continue; 'h' <enter> for help.

|| 
|> \mymod {5}{3}

[===== Step 1 =====] \mymod = \long macro:#1#2->\my_mod:nn {#1}{#2}
|| 
|> \my_mod:nn {5}{3}

[===== Step 2 =====] \my_mod:nn = \long macro:#1#2->\int_set:Nn \l_t...
|| 
|> \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_div_truncate:nn {5}{3}}\int_eval:n
|> {(5)-\l_tmpa_int *(3)}

[===== Step 3 =====] \int_set:Nn = \protected\long macro:#1#2->#1=\_...
|| 
|> \l_tmpa_int =\__int_eval:w \int_div_truncate:nn {5}{3}\__int_eval_end:
|> \int_eval:n {(5)-\l_tmpa_int *(3)}

[...steps omitted...]

[===== Step 63 =====] )
|| \tex_the:D 
|| \__int_eval:w (5)-1*(3)
|> \__int_eval_end: 

[===== Step 64 =====] \tex_the:D =>2
|| 
|> 2

[===== Step 65 =====] 2
<| 2
|| 
|> 

[===== End =====]
```

Since you're learning, a few words of advice. The function `\my_mod:nn` should be `protected`, because you do an assignment. But you can avoid it:

```
\cs_new:Npn \my_mod:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_eval:n { (#1) - \int_div_truncate:nn {#1}{#2} * (#2) }
 }
```

Comment: Wow! There are so many steps! Thanks for your "unravel" secret. I learned something new today which is not in official documentation. Nevertheless, I still don't see how ```\cs_show:N``` or ```\cs_show:c``` works. And this is what I'm interested for. I'll still keep the question opened for a while and if no one will give an answer where it's used ```\cs_show``` I will close it considering your answer as a correct one.